# Using Google Maps and Angular JS. Trying to store coordinates in variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

FYI, I'm new to AngularJS. I'm trying to store coordinates of marker selected in Google Maps in a variable. I am able to log the coordinates once I select a point on the map but I can't figure out why $scope.map.markers is returning "undefined" in addSesh(). Please let me know if you need further clarification. Thanks in advance!

```
angular
  .module('surfSup')
  .controller('SessionController', function($scope, $location, SessionService, CacheEngine, $rootScope) {
$scope.addSesh = addSesh;
  function addSesh () {
      $scope.sessionObjs = {
        time: $scope.time ? $scope.time.toISOString().slice(0,19) : "",
        isSurf: $scope.suppy,
        location: $scope.location
      };
      console.log("session obj", $scope.sessionObjs);
      console.log("map coords: ", $scope.map.markers);
      SessionService.addSession($scope.sessionObjs).then(function(res){
        console.log('session created', res);
        $location.path('/sessions');
    }
$scope.map = {
      center: {
          latitude: 32.7799400,
          longitude:-79.9341970
      },
      zoom: 11,
      markers: [],
      events: {
      click: function (map, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
          var e = originalEventArgs[0];
          var lat = e.latLng.lat(),lon = e.latLng.lng();
          var marker = {
              id: Date.now(),
              coords: {
                  latitude: lat,
                  longitude: lon
              }
          };
          $scope.map.markers.push(marker);
          console.log('MARKERS:', $scope.map.markers);
          window.glow = $scope.map.markers;
          $scope.$apply();
      }
  }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

(Not enough info) but try to set a breakpoint in the log line `$scope.maps` and inspect it in chrome dev tools. See if not only `$scope.maps.markers` is undefined but also `$scope.maps` (it may be also undefined). Then backtrack.

Comment: I did try this and I'm able to log $scope.maps but it seems like the data is not binding to $scope.map.markers because it keeps returning an empty array.

Comment: Empty array is different than undefined. And you are initialising markers to empty array.

Comment: Yup, and when I console.log('MARKERS:', $scope.map.markers); it returns an array with coordinates but for some reason it's empty when I try to pass it in the addSesh() function. In other words, I select the marker, and I'll log $scope.map.markers which stores the coordinates, but then I try to pass $scope.map.markers in the addSesh() function and it just returns an empty array.

Comment: I think I know my problem but I don't know how to fix it. When I'm selecting my markers, the  are not binding to the scope.